# emberjs recipes : before/action filter, controller namespace, shared object

Tags: javascript, filter, ember.js, namespaces, dom-events

We started a project with rails 4 beta and emberjs 1.0.0rc1.

I'm looking for "recipes" or patterns for the following problems:

1. Have/simulate "before filters", for example redirect a user when there is no current user
2. Have controllers and models namespace, like /admin/videos | /videos | /member/videos for accessing different collections based on your role (admin/videos returns all videos, /videos only public videos and /member/videos only my videos for example...)
3. When and where to load and store a shared object, for example, currentUser ? It should be available everywhere, like "rails" current_user (We use needs for now or App.set(), but not really happy with it
4. Best way to catch an event on "document" DOM element, not emberjs application view (for example Hide/show a menu like facebook user menu) : I click on an icone to show it, I click on the DOM document to hide it (sometimes outside of my ember application...

Answer (score 0):

1. you have a `redirect` hook on the `Ember.Route`. It is documented on the website.
2. I am not sure how this is relevant to client side app. I would imagine this kind of filters on the backend.
3. `needs` or  `App.inject` is definitely what you want. You should have a `currentUser` controller and require/inject it on all of your controllers.
4. Maybe register a handler in `ApplicationRoute` and dispatch router events from there.

Some notes :

`App.inject` and `App.register` should be called outside of any hooks like this :

`App.inject('controller', 'gobalUser', 'controller:currentUser');`

Comment: 1. how do you manage auto-generated routes ?
2. how would you manage in the same client application the different views/templates for guest/admin/member roles ? When I load public videos, I won't have same information as admin attributes...

Comment: 1. If you need redirect you should override any auto-generated routes
2. well, if you want the same pages to look differently for different roles, you can use a combination of {{#if isAdmin}} and inside {{partial}} / {{render}} different templates

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to do this for example :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend 
  setupController: ->
    App.register('controller:currentUserController', App.CurrentUserController );
    App.inject('controller', 'gobalUser', 'controller:currentUserController');
```

and we got this as error : 
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded